# Rollback edit summary doesn't re-render on mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, rollbacks

On rollback revisions, the user [edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/21960/ale?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=23&&__=1628199254) contains a GUID on the mobile site:

> [image: mobile]

Full web says "a previous revision":

> [image: full]

This appears to be the raw edit summary, according to a [chat message from Shog9](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6658697#6658697). This raw text is re-rendered on the desktop site in post and user edit histories; this doesn't seem to be taking place on the mobile site.